# Event preventDefault on document interferes with child event

Tags: javascript

I have an input element, with onChange event, and also an event listener for the whole document. When using the `preventDefault` function, it blocks the onChange event of the input element, so that callback will not run.

But as I understand, the document event listener occurs in the bubbling phase, **after** the input element events should trigger, therefore why would `preventDefault` on the document blocks events of the input child element?

My code:

```
export const App: FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => {
  document.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // This prevents onChange from running
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={() => {
          console.log('CHANGED!'); // Won't run
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-aggjje?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Comment: The preventDefault prevents input being typed. So, the input value never changes and the change event isn't triggered.

Comment: Yes I see, you mean that the onChange triggers after the press event occurs, and because they're separate events that occur one after the other, preventing it in the document will block the next event - onChange, in the input element?

Comment: Yes, they are separate events. The first event is the keypress, which would cause the input of a letter into the input field. That input into the input field would trigger the change event, which would then be handled by the onChange. But since preventDefault in the keypress handler stops the input from happening, the second event never happens.

Comment: Almost. @Geshode says that the "change" event _never occurs_, because by preventing the keyboard input, the value of the input _never changes_ and hence _there is no change event firing_.

Comment: What is the rationale of preventing keypresses on the document, if you're going to need keypresses?

Comment: @Teemu there isn't any rationale I was just trying to understand the concept

Comment: OK. Thought old, but still valid article of [the DOM event model](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link4).